# How to do a IIF function of sorts

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have 2 tables where in the first table I have the fields(`Area`[drop down list of Alasia,Kwambo,NECF,ect] and `Location`).

In the second table I have 5 fields that are the same as the `Area` and about 20 values for Each specific area.

```
SELECT Table2.[Alasia HO] FROM Table2 WHERE (((Table2.[Alasia HO])=[Table2.Alasia HO])); 

SELECT Table2.[Kwambo] FROM Table2 WHERE (((Table2.[Kwambo])=[Table2.Kwambo])); 

SELECT Table2.[NECF] FROM Table2 WHERE (((Table2.[NECF])=[Table2.NECF])); 

SELECT Table2.[Richmond] FROM Table2 WHERE (((Table2.[Richmond])=[Table2.Richmond])); 

SELECT Table2.[Rocky Ridge] FROM Table2 WHERE (((Table2.[Rocky Ridge])=[Table2.Rocky Ridge])); 

SELECT Table2.[Greytown] FROM Table2 WHERE (((Table2.[Greytown])=[Table2.Greytown]));
```

The above gives a drop down menu with a list items, I can only write one to get this result.

But I need all of the above in.

So basically I need function like this:

```
=iif(Table1.Area=Table2, (SELECT Table2.[Alasia HO] FROM Table2 WHERE (((Table2.[Alasia HO])=[Table2.Alasia HO])))
```

If false go to the next one in the above list.

I would greatly appreciate any help. Not very good in SQL.

Comment: what are you trying to do? whats your table definition and what is your expected result?

Comment: Your question is a bit confused and I dont get it even if I try hard. Try to read your question as if you knew nothing about your setup and find out what misses. - Are you talking about a form? about linked dropdowns?

Comment: I do applogise for the confusion. What i have done is link a mysql data base to Microsoft Access, just because i like the interface of it and i can create restritions on what can be entered and not.

Comment: But what i am trying to do is create a IF function within access. so basically if in the first column i select a value, then in the next column i want a list of values that is related to the first column results. wish is a defined in the second table.

Comment: So in other words, when selecting from a drop down menu int the first column, (one of four values), in the next column i want to only show a list in a drop down that is related to the first column result.

Comment: The above SQL notations are to fetch the list from the second table to the second column in the first table. but i cant get it to compare with the first value in the first table with the heading of the second table.

Comment: ... and you are trying to do this in the table directly? Afaik, Access doesn't support dynamic lists in the table-view. It is also not recommended to use the table-view directly - exactly because you have almost no way of controllng the input. Try to use Forms instead - there you shouldn't have problems doing what you want.